# automatically setting an environmental variable before invoking GUI app

Tags: windows-xp, environment-variables

I have a windows GUI app, say prog.exe, which is located in a folder in the system path. The app is not mine, and all I have is binary, so I can't change the program.

I have a file type, say *.typ, which I associate with prog.exe.

A particular file, say tst.typ, is located in some folder, say C:\tst, so the full path is C:\tst\tst.typ.

Next, in Windows Explorer, I open the folder C:\tst, and double-click on tst.typ. When I do that, prog successfully opens.

However prog takes no arguments, so although prog opens correctly, it doesn't know that it was invoked from the working directory C:\tst or from the file C:\tst\tst.typ.

But on startup, prog *does* check an environmental variable, say PROG_VAR.

Here's what I would *like* to happen when I double-click tst.typ from folder C:\tst:

- The environmental variable PROG_VAR gets set to C:\tst\tst.typ.

  prog.exe is then invoked (with the updated environment).

One approach is to change the association of *.typ so that it opens with a batch file, say prog.bat. Then prog.bat can correctly set the environmental variable PROG_VAR, and invoke prog.exe. The problem with that approach is that a command window will also show, and I don't want that. I only want to see the GUI window from prog.exe.

What are some ways to accomplish this objective?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use your batch file, then create a shortcut (`.lnk`) to it with window type set to "hidden". Now set this shortcut as a handler for the file typ `.typ`.

The point is, that the window style "hidden" is applied only to the initial window (the batch file), but not any susequent windows opened (i.e the GUI window)

Comment: Cool! I'll try it . . .

Comment: Windows won't let me associate a file type to a shortcut. I can associate *.typ to say, prog.bat , or to an exe file, but if I use the a batch file, a cmd window will show.

Comment: When I try to associate *.typ to a desktop shortcut to prog.bat, I get the error message "tst.typ is not a valid win32 application". I'm running Windows XP Pro SP3.

Comment: OK, I didn't think of Windows 98 or XP - sorry, I have seen his work on Win 7.

Comment: No problem, it's good to know that it would work on Windows 7. I'll upgrade _eventually_!

Answer (score 0):

Open regedit.exe. Find the key for .typ association command line string which looks like

```
c:\somefolder\prog.exe "%1"
```

Update it with

```
cmd /c set PROG_VAR="%1" && c:\somefolder\prog.exe "%1"
```

It is to be enough.

Comment: This will show the command line console for a few moments.

Comment: Which is not ideal, but I guess I can live with that if nothing else works.

Comment: Of course... But I think it's not a critical problem.

Comment: Well, the flicker would be an annoying side affect, so an optimal solution is one which avoids that.